# Nuttx: why is polling required for work queue threads?

Tags: multithreading, embedded, rtos

The Nuttx worker threads (LP and HP) have a polling interval, only for worker thread 0. I am wondering why a polling interval is needed?

When someone queues a new work into the work queue, a worker thread will be signaled to handle it. And if all worker threads were busy, the queued work will be handled when a thread has finished current work and checks the queue again.

As about the sched_garbage_collection() work, the worker threads are signaled by sched_signal_free().

So what is the case when a polling interval is required? It seems signals are good enough to make sure worker threads are always kicked to process the works.

Comment: I am not familiar with NuttX specifically, but cannot find any reference to the behaviour you describe in the documentation - add a citation or example.  Many of the terms you use do not appear in the documentation, or appear to be used in different ways.  When you talk about "worker threads" are you in fact referring to "work queues"?

Comment: "worker threads" are the threads created by Nuttx it self to handle the works queued into the "work queues". The Nuttx core itself has 2 work queues, a low priority one and a high priority one. Both of queues are bound to one or more worker threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polling is not required.  It is just there as a failsafe.  I was afraid of the consequence if a notification signal were lost.  That would, of course, be a bug and since I am aware of no such bugs, I have to say that that the polling is unnecessary and a waste of CPU cycles.

Another issue is the default rate of the poll which is, as I recall, 50 MS. That turns out to be one of the higher rate activities and for the highest priority task.  You could set that to a much lower rate.  If you want to add an option to disable the polling, that might be a good thing too.